# Сочетание горячих клавиш

Tags: c#, winforms

Проблема заключается в том, что сочетание клавиш вовсе не является сочетанием. Достаточно лишь одного нажатия на alt, чтобы всё работало. Мне необходимо именно сочетание ctrl-alt-c.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{    
    bool turn = true;    

    // ненужный код опущен

    private void Form1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Control && e.Alt) 
        {
            turn = false;
        }
        else
        {
            turn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Код текстом. 2) Что за бред в процедуре XXX?(номера строки невидно, скопировать текст с картинки не выходит)

Comment: Посмотрите ещё раз

Comment: Для начала, без функции `Form1_PreviewKeyDown` все работает нормально или нет?(если нет - проблемы в этом коде точно нет)

Comment: Полагаю, проблема в том, что при нажатии _любой_ клавиши значение `turn` сбрасывается в `1`.

Comment: Второе - учитесь писать красивый код, та же функция, меняем `int turn = 1` на `bool turn = true` а содержимое функции на `if(e.KeyCode == Keys.C&&e.Control&&e.Alt) turn = !turn` заодно поведение функции станет таким как вы задумали

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, просвятите неуча(меня), что цэ за язык и как эта досадная опечатка может влиять на копирование? или таки функция переопределяет обработку клавиш а не просто вклинивается посередине ничего не меняя?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков
Выяснил 
Что достаточно только нажатия клавиши alt.
Все остальные можно не нажимать.
Не подскажете,
как таки сделать комбинацию?

Comment: Прочтите пример изменений в коде выше по комментариям, если у вас уже всё так, но ошибка с копированием сохраняется(или поведение не то которого вы хотели добится) - измените вопрос, чтобы понимать что именно вы хотите получить, и как именно код выглядит на данный момент

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков изменил вопрос, добавил код